# Making one radio input change when another radio input is checked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a form using some radio inputs. When the input is checked, another radio is also checked automatically using jQuery.

For example:

question1: A(checked), B, C
question2: D(auto checked), E, F

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <tr>
      <td>
     
        <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="radio" value="A" name="teamA" /> A<br />
          <input type="radio" value="B" name="teamA" /> B<br />
          <input type="radio" value="C" name="teamA" /> C<br />
    <br /><br />
      </td>
      <td></td>
         <input type="radio" value="D" name="teamB" /> D<br />
         <input type="radio" value="E" name="teamB" /> E<br />
         <input type="radio" value="F" name="teamB" /> F<br />
        </form>
      </td>
     </tr>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ch Sunrain - why have you not selected an answer? I provided you an efficient JQuery-centric answer, & fixed some HTML to make it more compliant and efficient - once you select an answer a "green checkmark" will appear beside it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can u try with below code it may be help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <table>
     <tr>
  <td>


     <input type="radio" value="1" name="teamA" /> A<br />
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="teamA" /> B<br />
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="teamA"   /> C<br />
<br /><br />
  </td>
  <td></td>
     <input type="radio" value="1" name="teamB" /> D<br />
     <input type="radio" value="2" name="teamB" /> E<br />
     <input type="radio" value="3" name="teamB" /> F<br />

  </td>
 </tr>
     </table>
</form>
<script>
 $(function(){
    $('input[name="teamA"]').click(function(){
       var teamAVal=$(this).val();
         if ($(this).is(':checked'))
          {
             $('input[name="teamB"]').each(function( index ) {
             console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
             if($( this ).val()==teamAVal){
                    $( this ).prop('checked', true);
              }
             });
          }
   });
  });
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This answer matches my question

Comment: Your question asked for a jQuery solution, the above does not utilize jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to change the radio button selection as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#step1').on('change', function() {
   //alert($('input[name=teamA]:checked', '#step1').val()); 
   
   if($('input[name=teamA]:checked', '#step1').val()=='A')
 {
     $('input[value=D]').prop("checked", true);
   }
   else if($('input[name=teamA]:checked', '#step1').val()=='B')
 {
     $('input[value=E]').prop("checked", true);
   }
   else if($('input[name=teamA]:checked', '#step1').val()=='C')
 {
     $('input[value=F]').prop("checked", true);
   }
   else
 {
 alert("wrong selection");
 // $('#step2').prop("checked", true);
   
   }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<tr>
  <td>
    <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label> Question 1 </label><br />
    <div id="step1">
     <input type="radio" value="A" name="teamA" /> A<br />
      <input type="radio" value="B" name="teamA" /> B<br />
      <input type="radio" value="C" name="teamA" /> C<br />
      </div>
<br />
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <label> Question 2 </label><br>
  <div id="step2">
     <input type="radio" value="D" name="teamB" /> D<br />
     <input type="radio" value="E" name="teamB" /> E<br />
     <input type="radio" value="F" name="teamB" /> F<br />
     </div>
    </form>
  </td>
 </tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please follow my code to answer, don't copy other code!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient use of jQuery to do the job you asked for (w/ jQuery). I also cleaned up some of the html:

1. you were missing  start & end tags
2. I put form tag outside table (as the parent) as it was previously started in one row-cell  and ended in another which
   is non-standard html
3. added labels around inputs - it's the expected UI / standard best-practice when somebody clicks the 'A' it's as if they clicked
   the radio button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//on any change in teamA
   $("[name=teamA]").change(function() {

     //get the index of clicked item (this) among set of teamA
     //A is 0, B is 1, C is 2 within teamA, 
     //C is 0, D is 1, E is 2 within team B 
     //it's their order within the set
     var clickedItemIndex=$(this).index("[name=teamA]");
      $("[name=teamB]").eq(clickedItemIndex).prop("checked",true);
      
   });
});
```

```css
   
label { display: block }  /* brs are a nuisance, display: block */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--1. Another item you may have missed is that your code is missing <table> start and end blocks
       2. I also took your form and put it OUTSIDE your table, it's not good form to start a form in one cell (a td block) and then end in another when you can just put the form as the parent to the table.
       3. I added labels around inputs as that's standard best-practice, it means when somebody clicks the 'A' it's as if they clicked the radio, again - the expected standard UI of the web
    -->
  <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label><input type="radio" value="A" name="teamA" /> A</label>
          <label><input type="radio" value="B" name="teamA" /> B</label>
          <label><input type="radio" value="C" name="teamA" /> C</label>
          
        </td>
        <td>
          <label><input type="radio" value="D" name="teamB" /> D</label>
          <label><input type="radio" value="E" name="teamB" /> E</label>
          <label><input type="radio" value="F" name="teamB" /> F</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```